# Gnome3 can not set energy saving properties

Tags: gnome3, power-management, monitors

Neither using the Settings application nor the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 120
```

Does have any affect on turning the monitor idle.

Comment: Are you using X and if so, is DPMS enabled according to `xset -q`?

Answer (score 0):

GUI : To change the keys you can use “dconf Editor “.

it worked fine for me.

edit : try flipping values of org/gnome/desktop/session idle-delay to 300
( the values are in seconds, so 300 = 5 min

[image]utes )

Comment: What keys are you changing? Could you flesh out this answer a little bit to describe how it would solve the problem at hand?

Comment: values of org/gnome/desktop/session idle-delay, it does exactly what the command says.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP reports as _not working_ (we're talking about the same `dconf` key). Saying "it's working for me" doesn't help much...